# State verb and past perfect make me apprehensive

Tags: sentence-construction

> A: He thought he had remembered everything until he got to the church and realized the ring was at home.
> B: He had been thinking he had remembered everything until he got to the church and realized the ring was at home.

Which sounds more natural, A or B? I think B describes my thinking better, but my grammar book says it is not acceptable to make a continuous form when the verb is a state verb - in this case 'think' is that.

If B is possible, another question comes up to me: if it is OK to have two past perfect expressions in one sentence as B does. Does B make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the continuous with state verbs, but it has a different meaning that usually isn’t the one you want.

- I think I will go to the store today.

This means I intend to go to the store today, with the expectation that I will do so.

- I am thinking I will go to the store today.

This also means I *currently* intend to go to the store, but I’m not sure I actually will because *later* I might think differently. This emphasizes the possibility of changing your mind about something, but some speakers (and textbooks) don’t seem to believe you’re allowed to do that.

- I am thinking about going to the store today.

This means I have not yet decided whether I will go.